# ¿Alguna manera de utulizar variable que se ubica abajo, para una condicional primera?

Tags: php

buen día. Les comento, tengo un problema, tengo que utilizar una variable que está inicializada en la linea `88`, la tengo que utilizar en la linea `52`, en un condicional, capaz no se entiende, pero dejo parte del codigo:

```
 if ((date('d/m/Y', $day[$total]) == $fecha_actual)/* || (strlen($minutos) > 0)*/) { //linea 52, $minutos no está inicializada aún
    $contadores[0]=$contadores[0]+1;
    $total=$total+1;
 }
```

Luego, con la suma "`$contadores[0]`" la uso en un `for`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $contadores[0]; $i++) {
    $final = array();
    foreach($html->find('div[class="b_match_status b_match_info-elem"]') as $element) {
      array_push($final, $element->plaintext);
    }
$minutos = $final[$total];
}
```

Y acá si se inicializa por primera vez, dentro del for, que en cada iteración esa variable $minutos toma el valor de la otra variable, todo funciona, pero solo me falta ese detalle.
Se que no se puede usar, pero alguna manera tiene que existir.

Otro dato a tener en cuenta: `$contadores[0]` está inicializada en `-1`, porque puede que a veces no tenga que entrar al `for`.

Comment: Vos queres saber con anticipacion el valor de algo que vas a calcular despues?

Comment: exacto, porque dentro del for, si es que entra, $minutos toma un valor, que necesito para luego usarlo en el if

Comment: luego o antes? porque minutos va a tomar varios valores... o no?